# First edition of Mesillas Yesharim available online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, ramchal

The first edition of the Mesillas Yesharim was printed in Amsterdam in 1740. I have seen the cover page online but I would like to see the entire book online. Is it available anywhere?

I have checked Hebrewbooks and I did a general search on Google but had no luck.

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D claims that http://aleph500.huji.ac.il/nnl/dig/books/bk001762123.html is the first edition. Alas, that second link is dead. But perhaps you can find the book on that site (perhaps by parsing that URL).

Answer (score 4):

This sefer is available on the Otzar Hachochmah program.

You can also view the sefer here:
https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?53447

The first 40 pages are available for viewing for free. 
Beyond that you need to pay...

Comment: IsraelReader, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for answering this question! I hope we keep seeing you around perhaps elsewhere in the [tag:jewish-books] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. First edition can be found on the site of the National Library of Russia, [here](https://dlib.rsl.ru/viewer/01006544118#?page=3).